# Scheme missing expression after datum sequence

Tags: scheme, case, expand

When I run this in DrRacket, I receive the error: "case: bad syntax (missing expression after datum sequence) in: ((else exp))."

Here is the code

```
(define expand (lambda (exp) 
(if (pair? exp)
(case (car exp)
    ((let) (expand(let-expansion (exp))))
    ((and) (expand(and-expansion (exp))))
    ((or) (expand(or-expansion (exp))))
    ((let*) (expand(let*-expansion (exp))))
    ((letrec) (expand(letrec-expansion (exp))))
    ((cond) (expand(cond-expansion (exp))))
    ((case) (expand(case-expansion (exp))))
    ((else exp))))
((exp))))
```

Not sure what is causing the error. I am new to scheme so it is possible that I am not understanding the syntax correctly.

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a parentheses problem, try this:

```
(define expand 
  (lambda (exp) 
    (if (pair? exp)
        (case (car exp)
          ((let)    (expand (let-expansion    exp)))
          ((and)    (expand (and-expansion    exp)))
          ((or)     (expand (or-expansion     exp)))
          ((let*)   (expand (let*-expansion   exp)))
          ((letrec) (expand (letrec-expansion exp)))
          ((cond)   (expand (cond-expansion   exp)))
          ((case)   (expand (case-expansion   exp)))
          (else exp))
        exp)))
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you, I removed a lot of seemingly unnecessary parentheses, but I'm not sure how `exp` is supposed to look, so there might be bugs lurking